# How to use [*] JSONPath Wildcard In order to retrieve array values

Tags: karate, jsonpath

I am attempting to retrieve the `animalId` values from the response. The array is dynamic and so therefore I am attempting to use `def animalIds = response.animals[*].animalId` to retrieve the `animalId` values from the array.

Response:

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "animalId": "1234565",
            "animalName": "Tom"
        },
        {
            "animalId": "1234567",
            "animalName": "Dave"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I execute my feature file, I receive the following error:

```
response.animals[*].animalsId
                  ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 18

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: there are test failures !
        at ...(.)
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
* def animalIds = $response.animals[*].animalId
```

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-short-cuts